# azure datafactory pig activity cannot read input

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

Trying to run a Azure Data-factory pipeline containing a pig activity which runs on on-demand HDI cluster and reads from a azure-storage dataset linked service. The script reads input and store to a different similar dataset.

I am able to run the pipeline and the on-demand cluster also seems to be created but my activity failed with a pig error

`ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: wasb://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/inp`

"mystorage" is a general purpose storage account with standard tier. In this account i opened the blob link and created a container named "inp" which containes few uploaded files.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using the `wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/` syntax?

Comment: This worked for me i made input.txt as my input file and changed my path to `wasb://inp@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/input.txt`and it works just fine. Thanks for your quick response.